# Z-index on a absolute container in a fixed containter

Tags: z-index

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owPde.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc9ma.png)

```
header{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        background-color: $color;
        width: $width;
        height: 56px;
    }

.utility{
        @include lockPosition(10px);
        right:10px;
        width:700px;
        height:20px;
        padding-top:10px;
        z-index:1000;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

I find that only absolute position fixes the z-index issue I am having but I want the header to be fixed so it does scroll. Is there a way to have a absolute position in a fixed element and not effect the z-index?

Comment: What's @include lockPosition, is that a mixin?

Comment: yea, I just noticed I have position set to absolute twice, but that doesn't matter: `@mixin lockPosition($topMargin:100%){
 position:absolute;
 top:$topMargin; 
}'

Comment: Just wondering why do you use float right on the .utility?

Comment: Maybe it be easier if i'll be able to see how you want the layout to look like

Comment: added a screenshot of the issue I am having. It is showing on scroll.

Comment: so I guess it can only be absolute, absolute, parent child combo for z-index to show properly. You can't have fixed, absolute in a parent child container combo for z-index to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to push down the box with absolute position, i guess on .utility,

```
.utility{top: npx}
```

As for your question, the importances of the z-index is depending on how you lays the HTML DOM, so for example if your

```
<header>Your fixed position</header>
<main>
 <nav>Your absolute position</nav>
</main>
```

with your fixed position z-index will be much more important than your

Hope that helps,

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working. I have changed the header to fixed and .utility(child element) to absolute.

Comment: Did you add top: xx px on the absolute? or margin-top: xx px on the absolute element?

Comment: So .utility is inside the <header> ?

Comment: If it is i think you should place it outside the header, cause position fixed isn't the same as relative

Comment: .utility{
 position:absolute;
 right:10px;
 width:700px;
 height:20px;
 padding-top:10px;
 z-index:1000;
 top: 0px;
} doesn't work

Comment: try top: 50px, you need to adjust it according to the height of your header, all you need to do is to push the absolute element below fixed element

Comment: if I put that container outside of the fixed container it will scroll with the page and I don't want it to scroll. The utility nav has to stay fixed in the header. Know what I mean? I tried your thing of adding top:0px to the absolute positions child element and it didn't work.

Comment: No worries :) Happy to help!